# Is there a way to have a persistent object in memory I can read/write to anywhere in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails based web backend, and I've ran into a bit of an issue. I'm building a crypto trading based application, which relies on knowing the exact current price of many cryptos/stocks. To do this I seem to need a websocket to update certain data, however I can't figure out how to store this data. I need to be able to write to it on every websocket update, as well as read from it when sending out data to the front end. Both of these actions seem too fast to rely on my database, so I'm wondering if there is a better option. My idea was to use a class with a class method that is set on server startup. Then read from/write to that method when needed. The class looks something like this

```
class CryptoSocket
  def self.start
    @@cryptos = {
      BTC: 0,
      ETH: 0,
      DOGE: 0
    }
  end

  def self.value(symbol)
    @@cryptos[symbol]
  end
end
```

Inside the start method is a websocket which gets opened, and on message writes to @@cryptos with the updated value of the coin. I `call CryptoSocket.start` when the server boots up

To get the value for a symbol I can just call `CryptoSocket.value(symbol)` anywhere in my app. This seemed like it was working, however I've noticed sometimes it fails telling me `NameError: uninitialized class variable @@cryptos in CryptoSocket`
It seems like the issue is running `reload!` in the rails console, or entering a `binding.pry` then exiting. My guess is some garbage collection is happening, but overall it's something I'd like to avoid.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a better way to go about setting this class up? Does rails have a better way to persist an object in memory? It's fine to lose it when the server shuts down, but I would like to keep access to it when the server stays up

Comment: Hey check this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#use-case-1-during-boot-load-reloadable-code

Comment: Using a class variable is just a straight up bad idea due to reloading and thread safety. You should look into using memcached or redis.

Comment: You might look into OpenStruct (a fancy Hash object) to carry the info in memory.
If you need an actual Class, then use Struct.
https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/06/ruby-struct-and-openstruct